# C# WPF Dynamic UniformGrid

Tags: wpf, uniformgrid

I have a textbox where you can input an integer (which will the size of the UniformGrid). On a button click, a UniformGrid is generated with each grid contains some textblock, textbox, and a button, generated under different ElementName. I went through so many tutorial and all simply Add something to the children. And I can't seem to set the binding logic worked out - which bind to what, and which is being itemcontrolled. I went through wpftutorial and it just confuses me further.  Appreciate if anyone can explain the logic in simple terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UniformGrid` cannot really be used as an `ItemsHost` for an `ItemsControl`, mainly because the `DataTemplate` can only take a single child, which prohibits its use in this context.

Here's an alternative approach that might help you achieve what you want (I think)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
<ListView.View>
  <GridView>
    <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
      </Style>
    </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
    <GridView.Columns>
      <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeLabelText}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
      <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeInputText}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
      <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding SomeButtonLabel}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView.Columns>
  </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```